# How do I export a to an excel spreadsheet using powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, scripting

I have this PowerShell script that strips html tags and just leaves the text and have it display the word count for that html file when the script is executed. My question is when I execute:

```
function Html-ToText {
param([System.String] $html)

# remove line breaks, replace with spaces
$html = $html -replace "(`r|`n|`t)", " "
# write-verbose "removed line breaks: `n`n$html`n"

# remove invisible content
@('head', 'style', 'script', 'object', 'embed', 'applet', 'noframes', 'noscript', 'noembed') | % {
$html = $html -replace "<$_[^>]*?>.*?</$_>", ""
}
# write-verbose "removed invisible blocks: `n`n$html`n"

# Condense extra whitespace
$html = $html -replace "( )+", " "
# write-verbose "condensed whitespace: `n`n$html`n"

# Add line breaks
@('div','p','blockquote','h[1-9]') | % { $html = $html -replace "</?$_[^>]*?>.*?</$_>", ("`n" + '$0' )} 
# Add line breaks for self-closing tags
@('div','p','blockquote','h[1-9]','br') | % { $html = $html -replace "<$_[^>]*?/>", ('$0' + "`n")} 
# write-verbose "added line breaks: `n`n$html`n"

#strip tags 
$html = $html -replace "<[^>]*?>", ""
# write-verbose "removed tags: `n`n$html`n"

# replace common entities
@( 
@("&amp;bull;", " * "),
@("&amp;lsaquo;", "<"),
@("&amp;rsaquo;", ">"),
@("&amp;(rsquo|lsquo);", "'"),
@("&amp;(quot|ldquo|rdquo);", '"'),
@("&amp;trade;", "(tm)"),
@("&amp;frasl;", "/"),
@("&amp;(quot|#34|#034|#x22);", '"'),
@('&amp;(amp|#38|#038|#x26);', "&amp;"),
@("&amp;(lt|#60|#060|#x3c);", "<"),
@("&amp;(gt|#62|#062|#x3e);", ">"),
@('&amp;(copy|#169);', "(c)"),
@("&amp;(reg|#174);", "(r)"),
@("&amp;nbsp;", " "),
@("&amp;(.{2,6});", "")
) | % { $html = $html -replace $_[0], $_[1] }
# write-verbose "replaced entities: `n`n$html`n"

return $html + $a | Measure-Object -word
}
```

And then run:

Html-ToText (new-object net.webclient).DownloadString("test.html")

it displays **4 words** that are displayed in the output in PowerShell. How do I export that output from the PowerShell window into a an excel spreadsheet with the column **words** and the count **4**?

Answer (score 0):

The CSV you want just looks like this:

```
Words
4
```

it's easy enough to just write that to a text file, Excel will read it. But you're in luck, the output of Measure-Object is already an object with 'Words' as a property and '4' as a value, and you can feed that straight into `Export-Csv`. Use `select-object` to pick just the property you want:

```
$x = Html-ToText (new-object net.webclient).DownloadString("test.html")

# drop the Lines/Characters/etc fields, just export words
$x | select-Object Words | Export-Csv out.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

---

I'd be tempted to see if I could use

```
$x = Invoke-WebResponse http://www.google.com
$x.AllElements.InnerText
```

to get the words out of the HTML, before I tried stripping the content with replaces.

Comment: I tried using: $x | select-Object Words | Export-Csv out.csv -NoTypeInformation and the only thing it spit out was words but not the count. Not sure why it didn't do both.

Comment: That makes two of us. `'word1 word2 word3 word4' | measure-object -Word | Select-Object words | ConvertTo-Csv  -NoTypeInformation` ...

Comment: that spits it out in the console window not in the .csv file. I still get just words but not an integer underneath it

Comment: 'word1 word2 word3 word4' | measure-object -Word | Select-Object words | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation spits out "Words" "2", but how would it spit out the number of words from the html file into the csv file?

Comment: I figured it out. What I did was added 

    + $a | Measure-Object -Word after the #html variable in the script and then ran:
    Html-ToText (new-object net.webclient).DownloadString("test.html") + select-Object Words | Export-Csv out.csv -NoTypeInformation

and it exported the word count

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. What I did was added 
    + $a | Measure-Object -Word after the #html variable in the script and then ran: 
    Html-ToText (new-object net.webclient).DownloadString("test.html") + select-Object Words | Export-Csv out.csv -NoTypeInformation and it exported the word count – josh s 1 min ago